# Автоматическая установка расширения с сайта?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Мне необходимо сделать сайт с автоматической установкой плагина.

Есть ли библиотека, или лучше метод из неё, которые будут предоставлять доступ к расширениям браузера, чтобы можно бы было реализовать данный функционал?

Comment: Автоматическая установка плагина? Неплохо. Нафиг безопасность будем ставить юзеру все что захотим. Нет такой возможности, можно дать ссылку на страницу расширения в хром сторе, не больше

Comment: Вы меня немного неправильно поняли, вообще задумка такова: "Пользователь нажимает кнопку "Установить", и после этого и происходит инсталляция данного плагина". Вот так вот будет правильно или нет ?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome полностью отказался от подобного функционала еще в конце прошлого года. Раньше было API для inline-установки, прямо со страницы, но его признали небезопасным и убрали. Так что на данный момент можно только загрузить расширение в хром стор и дать на него ссылку

> Уже объявлено, что отказ от inline-установки будет разделен на три этапа. Первый этап уже начался: с 12 июня 2018 года встраиваемая установка для новых расширений запрещена. Для них попытка использовать chrome.webstore.install() теперь окончится открытием страницы расширения в официальном каталоге. Второй этап стартует 12 сентября 2018 года. Осенью inline-установку запретят всем существующим расширениям вообще. И, наконец, третий этап: в декабре 2018 года, с релизом Chrome 71, метод inline-установки исчезнет из API окончательно. [Источник](https://xakep.ru/2018/06/13/no-more-inline-installation/)

С лисой такая же ситуация.

Comment: Т. е . всё-таки уже невозможно просто так взять и загрузить в браузер расширение с сайта?...

Comment: А с "Opera", "Edge" и "Safari" не подскажите ли случаем ?

Comment: Откройте поисковик и вбейте "инлайн установка %% имя_браузера%%" и найдете ответ. Но я более чем уверен, что она везде запрещена, так как юзер может случайно поставить себе плагин полный вирусов и рекламы